# Who is Tenga, son of Ingvar?

Tags: inheritance-cycle

When Eragon must

> travel through the Empire to return to his allies,

he finds a hermit who goes by the name of Tenga, who seems to possess a great deal of knowledge, and is researching some great project:

> It was unusual, then, for Tenga to possess one such compendium, but to 
>  Eragon’s amazement, he saw six others throughout the room, in
>  addition to writings on subjects ranging from history to mathematics
>  to astronomy to botany.

Later we learn that Angela knew him:

> The herbalist chuckled between breaths, then said, “I used a trick … I
>  learned from my master … Tenga … ages ago. May a thousand spiders bite
>  his ears and knobbly bits.”

What evidence do we have of Tenga's identity, history, or motivations? In other words, *who is Tenga*?

Comment: You're on a roll with these *Inheritance* questions! Keep 'em coming :-)

Comment: And wow, that was a fast accept.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I can't imagine I'll get a better answer for a while.

Comment: Tenga, when the walls fell.

Comment: I updated my answer after getting a response from Paolini. Not that it helped or anything.

Comment: @ibid - Well, I finally remembered to reward your answer.

Comment: @Adamant - I've asked him again and this time he gave me a "definitive" answer.

Comment: There is a very good change that he is "The Keeper of the Tower" mentioned in the new book.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**We don't know much other than what's in the books - what we *do* know from interviews etc. is catalogued below - but Paolini plans to say more about Tenga in a future Book 5.**

[Tenga the Hermit … Who is he and what does he seek?](http://www.shurtugal.com/2011/09/03/big-twenty-tenga-the-hermit-who-is-he-and-what-does-he-seek/) is a long and detailed essay at shurtugal.net - a fan site whose administrator, Mike Macauley, wrote the *official* companion book to the Inheritance series, *The Inheritance Almanac*, published by Paolini's own publishers.

If that's not canonical enough for you, we have an assortment of interview quotes from Paolini himself.

- From [this interview](http://www.shurtugal.com/2010/11/12/random-buzzers-qa-with-christopher-paolini-part-1/):

  > *If possible, could you tell us what it actually was that Tenga was looking/searching for?  Was he still trying to find out if the rocks in the Beor Mountains are affected by the moon stages or whatever it was (can’t remember what it was off the top of my head), or is it something different?*
  >
  > CP: Tenga was searching for something much more important than whether the rocks in the Beor Mountains are affected by the stages of the moon. However, it’s not something I want to go into at the moment. Rest assured, though, I will return to it.

  and:

  > *The man Tenga, will we be seeing more of him?*
  >
  > CP: No comment.
- From [this interview](http://www.shurtugal.com/2013/08/17/new-interview-we-talk-some-major-post-inheritance-information-with-christopher-including-dragons-eggs-angela-tenga-murtagh-and-more/):

  > *What happened to Tenga and why did you put him in Brisingr?*
  >
  > CP: Great question, no comment.
- And finally from [this one](http://www.shurtugal.com/2015/05/20/what-weve-recently-learned-about-book-5-murtagh-roran-arya-tenga-and-more-hint-its-a-lot-part-two/) about the planned Book 5:

  > *Will we find out more about Angela’s master [Tenga] and the possible idea that there is another race of humanoids out there?*
  >
  > CP: Yes.

Answer (score 10):

### A disciple of light and all things pertaining to radiance

> **Are there any (non plot-important) tidbits you can share about Tenga son of Ingvar, such as his favorite color or something?**
> Tenga is a disciple of light and all things pertaining to radiance. But do not make the mistake of confusing the disciple with the thing itself when he is -- in actuality -- the inverse rather than a mirror.
> ([Facebook AMA](https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=1565802433465004&id=424047514307174&comment_id=1565806536797927&reply_comment_id=1565839570127957))

Some other things we know about him:

- The question that Tenga was searching for was not whether the rocks in the Beor Mountains are affected by the stages of the moon.

> **If possible, could you tell us what it actually was that Tenga was looking/searching for?  Was he still trying to find out if the rocks in the Beor Mountains are affected by the moon stages or whatever it was (can’t remember what it was off the top of my head), or is it something different?**
> Tenga was searching for something much more important than whether the rocks in the Beor Mountains are affected by the stages of the moon. However, it’s not something I want to go into at the moment. Rest assured, though, I will return to it.
> <sub>([Random Buzzers Q&A with Christopher Paolini](http://www.shurtugal.com/2010/11/12/random-buzzers-qa-with-christopher-paolini-part-1/))</sub>

- Paolini describes him as "crazy", "skilled", and "powerful".

> **Why does [Eragon] run away from Tenga?**
> Eragon ran away from Tenga because . . . well, would you want to hang around a crazy guy who could kill you with a single well-placed (or misplaced) word? Tenga may have been skilled and powerful, but I don’t think Eragon would have learned anything useful from him without spending a lot more time with him, gaining his trust, and Eragon had to get back to the Varden as fast as he could.
> <sub>([Random Buzzers Q&A with Christopher Paolini](http://www.shurtugal.com/2010/11/16/random-buzzers-qa-with-christopher-paolini-part-3/))</sub>

- He created the spell Eragon uses to transport the eldunaries.

> **When Eragon and Saphira leave the vault of souls, the eldunari shrink their existence into a teeny spec. They say the trick was developed by a hermit a few hundred years ago. Was this the weird dude living in a shack trying to figure something out about the moon?**
> Yup, that was him.
> <sub>([Reddit AMA](https://www.reddit.com/r/books/comments/g4vfqt/im_christopher_paolini_author_of_eragon_and_to/fo25wuz/))</sub>

- He isn't Angela's father.

> **Is Angela the daughter of Tenga?**
> No.
> <sub>([Reddit AMA](https://www.reddit.com/r/Eragon/comments/8fpwfo/i_am_christopher_paolini_ama_starting_2pm_mt/e16f5lf/?context=3))</sub>

- Tenga's father is dead.

> **Is tenga's dad dead?**
> Yes.
> <sub>([Reddit AMA](https://www.reddit.com/r/Eragon/comments/mwyi2h/ama_christopher_paolini_1000_am_mt1200_pm_eastern/gvy40xf/?context=3))</sub>

- Many of things that we see him doing may have simpler explanations.

> **In Brisingr, you show that spells can be put on a objects to activate when certain stimuli are present (for instance the anti-scrying spell on Eragon’s necklace).  If this is the case, isn’t it at least theoretically possible that Tenga had set up a spell that would automatically start the fire when he reached out with his mind, thus avoiding the dangers of not saying the spell out loud?  How did Eragon know that this wasn’t what was happening?**
> That’s entirely possible . . . and maybe Tenga was just trying to impress Eragon. Either way, he just succeeded in scaring Eragon off.
> <sub>([Random Buzzers Q&A with Christopher Paolini](http://www.shurtugal.com/2010/11/12/random-buzzers-qa-with-christopher-paolini-part-1/))</sub>

- After the war, he killed the spellcasters that Nasuada had sent to hunt him down and fled.

> The most serious altercation occurred when Nasuada sent four of her pet spellcasters to find a magician—a hermit by the name of Tenga—whom Eragon discovered while traveling alone in the wastes between Helgrind and the Burning Plains (as described in one of my earlier reports). However, the spellcasters never returned. At Nasuada’s request, Arya and Fírnen went to investigate. They found the four lying dead outside the elven watchtower where Tenga had been living and Tenga fled to parts unknown. As of yet, naught else has been heard of him, which is worrisome. The situation bears close attention. Still, Nasuada remains undaunted, and she continues to seek out and establish hold over the spellcasters of Surda and her kingdom.
> <sub>([*Letter from Jeod*](http://www.paolini.net/2015/07/09/deluxe-content-letter-from-jeod/))</sub>

- We will find out more about Tenga in the upcoming fifth novel.

> **@NarcysDope: Will we find out more about Angela’s master Tenga and the possible idea that there is another race of humanoids out there?**
> Christopher: Yes
> <sub>([Twitter](https://twitter.com/paolini/status/580212229754085376))</sub>

- I've tried finding out more, but was met with a *No Comment*.

> **Can you tell us anything new about Tenga, son of Ingvar?**
> No comment. :D
> <sub>([Reddit AMA](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fantasy/comments/4i0tf1/hey_reddit_im_fantasy_author_christopher/d389eqe))</sub>

Comment: Wrote this answer long before the other was posted, I had just apparently forgot to post it. As it stands it is somewhat different either-way.